# How to make WinSCP .NET assembly perform faster?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, winscp, winscp-net

Has anyone come up with speed performance using WinSCP .NET?

I try the C# WinSCP example in http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp. I note that when it starts up, it takes some 30 seconds to reach the first statement (the initialization of `WinSCP.SessionOptions`).

Anyone knows what is going on? How to speed up?

The thing I have to do is to write a C++ program (be it C++/CLI or plain C++) to automate some SFTP transfers which may happen per minute, per X minute, per hour, or even per day. Speed is a concern for me, especially transfers happen per minute. If there is another library which can perform better, please also let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The same question cross-posted on WinSCP support forum, without definitive answer so far: http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13651 (requires registration for access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out! Sorry about that. It is version mismatch. The version of WinSCP.exe is different from WinSCPnet.dll (the assembly).

I use the [source code of the latest version of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). I use the dotnet\WinSCPnet.csproj in the source. I add the project to the C# example. Compile the assembly and then C# example. The example runs immediately, but then I see a message saying the compiled assembly has a version mismatch between dot net assembly and WinSCP.exe.

Once I make sure both (assembly and EXE) are the same version (5.5.2), the C# example runs successfully (without any startup delay).

[EDIT] *Actually the delay happens in 5.5.1!*

I play around with version 5.5.1 and 5.5.2. I use version 5.5.1 EXE and dot net assembly with the C# example. When the program starts up, there is delay. I switch to version 5.5.2. When the program starts up, it runs immediately.

Hope this version information helps anyone needs to use WinSCP dot net assmebly.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved your problem. Though it does not really make any sense. The WinSCP .NET assembly does not interact with WinSCP until call to `Session.Open`. So any delay before that cannot be caused by incompatibility between those two.

Comment: There's only single line difference between 5.5.2 and 5.5.1 assemblies. And the line should affect COM interface only:
http://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=1134 So it rather looks like a local problem of yours.